# ¿Por qué no funciona esta expresión regular?

Tags: javascript, regex

Coloqué la siguiente *expresión regular*, la cual solo permite números y letras, el dilema es que, a veces, **no funciona, a pesar de que solo pongo números y letras**

Esta es la expresión regular:

```
/^[a-z0-9]+$/gi
```

[image: ¿Por qué no funciona esta expresión regular?]

Como ven, aquí, funciona de maravilla, pero agrego un número o una letra cualquiera y me salta el error

[image: ¿Por qué no funciona esta expresión regular?]

Y después, agrego cualquier otra letra o numero y se soluciona el error como ven en la siguiente imagen

[image: ¿Por qué no funciona esta expresión regular?]

No tengo ni idea del por qué se comporta de esa forma, espero logren ayudarme y gracias de antemano

Comment: El regex me parece correcto, seguro el problema es con el código

Comment: seria bueno que muestres tu código para verificar la validación

Comment: ¿Especificaste longitud mínima en el _input_?

Comment: Triby, si especifique que debe tener al menos 3 caracteres?

Answer (score -1):

logre solucionar el problema, lo único que cambie era que al final de la expresión coloque i en vez de gi, asi:

```
/^[a-z0-9]+$/i
```